# How can I refresh google map programmatically after using animateCamera()?

Tags: google-maps, location, maps

```
        newPosition = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoomLevel, tilt, currentBearing);

        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newPosition);

        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

When I zoom in or move the camera to another point using animateCamera(), it takes a long time for it to refresh the map (it looks blurry). But if I tap the screen or slightly move the camera manually after animation ends, it immediately refreshes.

[it looks like this after moving the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Oiw.png)

[I want it to refresh and look like this after animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoIQB.png)

I searched it in google maps documents but I didn't find a method for refreshing the map. Is there a way to refresh it programmatically?

Comment: Just by looking at the images, it looks like the map is just being loaded. That is, the map is downloading data from Google to render (vectors/rasters). There's no way to make it go faster. There is a `tiles_loaded` event for when the loading has finished.

Comment: Yes it is the map being loaded. However, if I touch the map it loads immediately. If I wait for it to load itself it takes a long time. So if it can load faster why doesn't it do that in the first place?

Comment: When the animation has finished, you can try setting the center or tilt or heading to force a render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by calling moveCamera() when the animation ends. I am moving the camera to the same location just to make google maps load the map immediately. Couldn't find a better way.

```
CameraPosition newPosition = newCameraPosition(newLatLng(latitude,longitude), zoomLevel, tilt, currentBearing);

CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newPosition);

googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
    @Override public void onCancel() {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
});
```